# Java/Groovy Custom comparator and filter array to leaveonly lowest values

Tags: java, groovy, comparator

I have this array:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "type": "A1",
    "text": "Bla bla bla 1 - A1"        
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "type": "A1",
    "text": "Bla bla bla 2 - A1"                
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "type": "A1",
    "text": "Bla bla bla 3 - A1"        
}
,
{
    "id": 1,
    "type": "A2",
    "text": "Bla bla bla 1 - A2"            
}]
```

I need to remove the duplicated "ids" leaving the one with the lower values (example A1 is lower than A2). So in the above example the record with id=1 and type=A2 should be removed.

In groovy I create this comparator:

```
class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Object>{

private HashMap<String, Integer> rank;

CustomComparator(){
    this.rank = new HashMap<>();
    this.rank.put("A1", 1);
    this.rank.put("A2", 2);
    this.rank.put("R5", 3);
    this.rank.put("R8", 4);
    this.rank.put("A4", 5);
}

@Override
public int compare(Object a , Object b){
   if(rank.get(a.type).intValue() < rank.get(b.type).intValue()){
       return -1;
   }
   if(rank.get(a.type).intValue() == rank.get(b.type).intValue()){
       return 0;
   }
   return 1;
}
```

}

And I'm trying to remove the duplicated using array.removeAll{} but can't find the right way. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Does it need to be a comparator? First thing that comes to my mind is to `groupBy` the `id` and then look for `min()` of `type`:

```
List list = [[
                     "id"  : 1,
                     "type": "A1",
                     "text": "Bla bla bla 1 - A1"
             ],
             [
                     "id"  : 2,
                     "type": "A1",
                     "text": "Bla bla bla 2 - A1"
             ],
             [
                     "id"  : 3,
                     "type": "A1",
                     "text": "Bla bla bla 3 - A1"
             ],
             [
                     "id"  : 1,
                     "type": "A2",
                     "text": "Bla bla bla 1 - A2"
             ]]

Map rank = [A1:1, A2:2, R5:3, R8:4, A4:5]

List cleaned = list.groupBy { it.id }
        .collect { k, v -> v.min { rank[it.type] } }
```

Comment: I was not thinking to group by.  It could be a good idea. The only concern about your solution is that it doesn't work always I think (depends on the type values) , that's why I was thinking to a comparator

Comment: Ah sorry, I did not take into account the rank of the types. I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Straigt-forward way to use simple sorting by two fields:

```
List list = [[
  "id"  : 1,
  "type": "A1",
  "text": "Bla bla bla 1 - A1"
],
[
  "id"  : 2,
  "type": "A1",
  "text": "Bla bla bla 2 - A1"
],
[
  "id"  : 3,
  "type": "A1",
  "text": "Bla bla bla 3 - A1"
],
[
  "id"  : 1,
  "type": "A2",
  "text": "Bla bla bla 1 - A2"
]]

def res = list.sort{ a, b -> a.id <=> b.id ?: b.type <=> a.type }.collectEntries{ [ it.id, it ] }.values()

assert res.toString() == '[[id:1, type:A1, text:Bla bla bla 1 - A1], [id:2, type:A1, text:Bla bla bla 2 - A1], [id:3, type:A1, text:Bla bla bla 3 - A1]]'
```

Comment: The concatination of the Spaceship operators with the Elvis operator is really elegant!